# Questions on graduate programs for Mathematics

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, mathematics, masters

I am an undergraduate Junior at UW Madison and I am finding myself really enjoying my recently declared mathematics major. I am exploring what it may look like for me to study math beyond a bachelors'. I was hoping that some grad students in Math, whether they are PhD or Masters, could answer some questions for me.

First and foremost, my GPA is not the best right now. I have heard that, especially in mathematics, admission can be competitive.

**Current:
 Cumulative - 2.98,
Math - 3.27**

I have had some mental health challenges in my time in college, as well as other challenges that a typical student doesn't have to face, including a loss of financial support from my family last year. Many of these things took a toll on my grades in my early years here. However I have rebounded and aced both of my classes last semester, and my current classes are going very well and I expect the trend to continue. I also think that, if I do apply to graduate programs, I could speak to my resilience in facing these matters, and how I am surviving and even thriving being a fully financially self supporting 21 year old student at a major university.

*One question I have is, will these admissions comittees hear my story and listen to me? Will they see my time here as a marker of resilience and perseverance given my context, or will they simply see the numbers and look past this context?*

So, I have 42 credits until I graduate. At most 27 of these credits could be math classes.

Based on this, I have estimated what my grades might look like if I keep doing well in my classes, with some error factored in.

**Predicted (mid range estimate): Cumulative 3.1, Math - 3.5**

So there is a solid estimate of what my GPA may look like once I graduate. Given that, I am somewhat concerned as to how the admissions process may look like for me just from what I hear about it. I think that I would be OK with going to an "average" program, as long as I can get funding for it.

So, here is one question!

*Where can I find fully or mostly funded graduate programs for mathematics that aren't so strict on GPA requirements?*

Another question I have. My current professor told me to do a Masters before doing a PHD to see if I like it. However, I have heard that many masters programs are NOT funded! I don't want to take out more loans, So,

*Where can I find masters programs in math that are mostly or fully funded?*

As far as location, I am open to considering all options.

From my own research into PHD programs, I've read that, although it is competitive, that admissions committees do take a somewhat holistic approach. Madison's program even states that they weigh letters of rec higher than grades. And, I am aware that a good GRE score could help a lot too.

Given that,

*From experience, can mathematics graduate students speak to this notion? Is it true that all factors are considered, or are some weighed more heavily than others? I understand this is likely different from university to university, but personal experience and knowledge would be valuable to me!
Given my current and predicted GPA, what do math grads think I should strive for? Should GPA even be a concern of mine, or should I instead focus on, for example, building strong relationships with faculty, or exploring undergraduate research?
On that note, what are things I can do now, besides working on my GPA, to increase my "job security" for getting accepted into a grad program?*

As for why I want to do a PHD: math is my primary academic strength, and it's something I really enjoy. Research sounds like it has the potential to be a highly engaging activity for me, and I love to learn and create new ideas.

Being a professor sounds cool, but I've heard the job market is tough, so right now I would say my primary motivation might be for the education and research experience, perhaps something with applied mathematics. But, theoretical and seeking professorships isn't off the table! I've still got a ways to go until I graduate (I'm a part time student so 42 credits will take me a bit longer than a full timer)

Thank you for reading! Feel free to ask any questions too.

Comment: Please add the relevant country tag to your question.

Comment: @Tommi, I think you can assume US here.

Comment: Also, the Stackexchange format tends to prefer it if you ask one question per post. So you could consider refining your question to just one, or asking separate questions. This may help you get better answers.

Comment: *However, I have heard that many masters programs are NOT funded!* --- My experience has been that it's quite rare for any mathematics graduate program in the U.S. to not provide funding, unless you're excluding being a T.A. In fact, I can't think of a single exception at the moment. Also, UW-Madison has one of the largest graduate math departments in the U.S. (possibly in the top 10), so you might try roaming around the graduate student offices and ask their advice. Although all are in a selective graduate program, most probably knew students in your position when they were an undergraduate.

Comment: Thanks for the info, new to stackexchange @astronat

Comment: Also, @DaveLRenfro you could be right - the masters program at UW Madison at least isn't funded(The PHD is, and you can walk away with a masters, but if you just do the masters alone it isn't funded to clarify, well technically they offer a little bit of work but it's not much), I may not have much evidence behind that belief then, what UW Madison has to offer is all I really know about masters programs and funding

Answer (score 1):

First, while I would give different advice, that from a prof at UW isn't to be ignored lightly. That prof knows you. But most doctoral students in the US start with just a BS/BA and "collect" an MS along the way to a doctorate. If you can get admitted to a doctoral program do that. If you decide that you don't like it you can probably do enough in most US programs to leave with an MS, perhaps by writing a "small" thesis. But the early part of the program is going to be largely coursework preparing you for comprehensive/qualifying exams.

Second, and most important, admissions committees don't want to hear your "story". Especially if it is is about why you didn't do well. What they want to hear is about the likelihood of your success and your preparation for their program. Your GPA is only part of that. Your GPA in the major is a bigger part. Letters from professors who can honestly predict your success are a big part many places.

No single thing is likely to get you into a program or deny you entry. Build a comprehensive picture of your solid work ethic, your preparation for the field, and the high probability of your success. Many facets to that.

Your "funding" in a doctoral program will most likely be as a TA. You spend up to about half your time assisting in the courses of professors. Later you might get to teach a course yourself. Less likely, but not impossible is an RA where you help someone in a research program, but this is a bit less common in math than in, say, chemistry. A fully funded, no obligation, scholarship is a far less likely opportunity, but they do happen. Most of these funding opportunities are not regularly given to MS candidates. The funding may be low, but it will probably be adequate and also comes with a grant that pays your tuition (usually).

Work hard. Develop good relationships with a few math professors.

Comment: That's a really interesting insight you had. I didn't really think too much of his comment, but yeah UW is a big math university and this guy in particular is a big name around here...and he does know me because this is my second class in a row with him. One thing I'm a bit worried about is being able to access relationships with professors at such a big school - but then again, barley anyone actually goes to office hours anyways so maybe it won't be so hard! It sure hasn't been with my current professor for the last two semesters

Comment: Staying at UW is a pretty good option if it is open to you.